# Nessus Professional - Create scan policy with custom plugins

Tags: nessus

I need to create a Nessus scanning policy for a custom set of plugins (90+), is there an easier way to do this rather than selecting each plugin one-by-one? I know there is an API you can use, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

Policy Library > Settings > Credentials > Compliance > Plugins

There are enable all and disable all settings in the upper right corner.